# Removing items from lists does not refresh correct components

Tags: .net-core, blazor

I have a Blazor page which display a list of components based on a list on which I dynamically add/remove items :

```
 <TelerikButton OnClick="() => State.AddSymbols(SymbolToAdd)">Add</TelerikButton>

@foreach (var symbolToDisplay in State.SymbolsToDisplay)
    {
        <StockGraph SymbolToDisplay="@symbolToDisplay" OnRemoved="() => State.RemoveSymbol(symbolToDisplay)"/>
    }
```

This is the code of the state :

```
 public void AddSymbols(string symbol)
    {
        SymbolsToDisplay.Add(symbol);
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void RemoveSymbol(string symbol)
    {
        SymbolsToDisplay.Remove(symbol);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

And the code of the component :

```
<div class="stock-graph">
<p>
    @companyData?.companyName
</p>
<div>
    <TelerikButton class="delete-item" onclick="@OnRemoved">X</TelerikButton>
</div>
<TelerikChart ref="@chart">
    <TelerikChartSeriesItems>
        <TelerikChartSeries Type="ChartSeriesType.Line" Data="@data.StockValues"
                            Field="@nameof(StockValueData.StockValue)"
                            CategoryField="@nameof(StockValueData.Date)">
        </TelerikChartSeries>
    </TelerikChartSeriesItems>
    <TelerikChartValueAxes>
        <TelerikChartValueAxis Color="red"></TelerikChartValueAxis>
    </TelerikChartValueAxes>
</TelerikChart>
```

This is supposed to be pretty straightforward. But for some reason when deleting a component it is always the last component displayed that is deleted even if the list has the required value removed and contains all the correct values.

I have a example of this code running on my github : [GitHubRepo](https://github.com/GuiguiMtl/FirstBlazorApp)

Just add random Stock symbols like GOOG, AAPL, ACC

Comment: This sounds like a problem with `OnRemoved()` but you didn't post that. I also find that first code piece hard to decypher, is that Blazor? Why the `() => ` and does that even work here?

Comment: That piece of code actually works and is coming from Dan Roth's Blazor Workshop "Blazing Pizza"

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that the issue was coming from the way I way initializing/updating the parameter of my component.
*OnInitAsync* is not run again after you require to update the data in the page and component.
Instead you have to use *OnParametersSetAsync* in order for the component to update its parameter correctly